# I am using hooks in expo framework react native, the whole code repeats 3 times even though I added an empty array

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo

I am using expo and used hooks as I need  the response to be saved in an array to access it later and I am not using classes so I found the hooks method, first it was giving me an infinite loop so when I searched I found that if I added an empty array as the second parameter in the useEffect() method this would make it run only 1 time but this is not happening as the code runs 3 times now, Is there any solution? If not is there another way to save the response in an array without classes rather than using hooks ?
The code below is what makes the problem.
Thank you in advance.

```
const [wallets, setWallets] = useState({});
async function fetchData() {
const res = await fetch('https://api.streetcred.id/custodian/v1/api/wallets', {
method: 'GET',
headers: {
Authorization: 'Bearer ',
XStreetcredSubscriptionKey: '',
Accept: 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
});
res
.json()
.then(res => setWallets(res))
.catch(err => setErrors(err));
}

useEffect(() => {
fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Could you provide your whole Hooks component? With this little information, your `useEffect` should run once. I'm afraid you are mounting the component several times.

Comment: What do you mean by mounting the component several times? I am sorry but I am new to react native. Also I believe this is the whole Hooks components I am using.

Comment: @Jolly I guess the problem occurs because the fetch does not return the values from the first time, The code repeats until all the data are retrieved from the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Write the function fetchData inside the useeffect method.

Comment: Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks

Comment: const [wallets, setWallets] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
const res = await fetch('https://api.streetcred.id/custodian/v1/api/wallets', {
method: 'GET',
headers: {
Authorization: 'Bearer ',
XStreetcredSubscriptionKey: '',
Accept: 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
});
res
.json()
.then(res => setWallets(res))
.catch(err => setErrors(err));
}, []);